# I Encrypted Ubuntu, now cannot remember passphrase. Help!

Tags: passphrase

I have an HP Envy Touchsmart m7 Notebook PC on which I replaced the original hard drive with a 256 GB Solid State drive.  On that I installed ubuntu in November 2014 and encrypted it.  I haven't used the computer since that time.  Now, when I start the computer, I can no longer remember the passphrase.

I do NOT care about losing the data... I just want to use the laptop.

What are my options?

Is there a command that will reset the computer? 
Do I have to wipe the hard drive and reinstall Ubuntu?  If so, what's the easiest way to do so?

I'm not a "techie" so please speak muggle.  :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think, the data is lost irreversibly, but you can reset root password, here's how you could do it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password meaning that after restoring root, you would have to replace the filesystem. But, probably, it would be easier to just boot from LiveUSB and install afresh.

Comment: Just reinstall it on the existing one. Choose the option to wipe, get the system to boot from usb via the BIOS settings for `boot order`

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-install as the data is unrecoverable. Do the following:

1. Create a bootable USB
2. Set the `boot order` from the `BIOS` to boot from that USB:

   - using [repeatedly hitting them] your <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> keys (depending on your system type) at reboot to get to `BIOS` settings. Go to advanced tab and alter the `boot order` to make the `USB` boot first.
3. Plug in the `USB` and follow the normal install instructions and select the option to erase and install `Ubuntu`

Comment: Thank you, all who responded.  I am now typing to you from the computer in question.  Obviously, things worked out well.  :)